# Film about a boy disguised as Killer robot on a space base

Tags: story-identification, space

The film opens up on some space base and there is this emphasis that the humans need to keep this diamond object safe because it stores their secrets or something like that. This is told to a generic blonde hero.

Meanwhile, there is a little kid wandering around the base and then his eyes glow red and he transforms into some killer robot and starts murdering everyone at the base.

The Diamond gets transported to Earth (somehow) and the blonde Hero is sent there to retrieve it and keep it safe. Meanwhile, the robots send one of their own (disguised as a blonde woman pretty sure) to get it as well.

There is a lot of (Terminatorish) commotion to retrieve the diamond and the local Italian Mafia gets involved, as they just want the Diamond, thinking it's worth a lot of money. There is one scene where the mob boss pulls out a rocket launcher out of his van and shoots it at the female robot (but obviously being sci-fi, she survives).

It was made in the 80s/90s for sure (i remember this pre-2000). It could potentially be a telemovie, or an actual movie, but I'm not sure. Also, I remember the title having something like "Battlestar" in it. (But believe me I have searched the *Battlestar Galactica*-related content, although perhaps I haven't searched hard enough.)

Comment: It seems to me that your title is backward.  It should be killer robot disguised as boy instead of boy disguised as killer robot.

Answer (score 2):

"Galaxis"(1995)?

(A.K.A. "Terminal Force")

It stars Brigitte Nielsen as a terminator-like alien. The movie does start on a spaceship or space station and involves a villain who is looking for a 'fire crystal'. Below is the trailer, and you can see a second or two of the boy turning into a killer robot at 1:23

Here is the plot summary from IMDb:

> Legend says that the sacred crystal is the source for all life and
>   was created at the beginning of time. Kyla has sought the crystal to
>   use its powers for himself and he takes the crystal after smashing the
>   defenders on the Planet Sintaria. But there is another identical
>   crystal on Earth and Ladera heads there to get it before the evil
>   Kyla. She finds that Jed has taken the crystal from is hiding place,
>   but Victor and his inexhaustible hit men want it for money they gave
>   to Jed. Ladera easily handles the weak earthlings and saves Jed, but
>   Kyla is also after the crystal. Jed and Ladera must find the crystal
>   before Kyla, the clueless cops or the dimwitted villains.

Answer (score -1):

One movie that is vaguely similar to your question is *Screamers* (1995) dealing with a civil war on an Earth colony on Sirius 6B.  There are some killer robots disguised as little boys.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screamers_(1995_film)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screamers_(1995_film))

https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/screamers-1996[2](https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/screamers-1996)

I don't think there is any action on planet Earth, though.